# How to seperate a String into parts with less that a defined length

Tags: javascript

I have a string (`this is the very very very very long string`) and what I want is to split it into part with less that 25 characters and the parts must have complete words like this:
`this is the very very`  and `very very long string` not `this is the very very ver` and `y very long string` .

Comment: You should really show a bit more of an initial effort. Several of your latest questions don't appear to show any at all, but are just plain "I need, you show" demands.

Comment: @CBroe , I know what you mean but it was more a question & answer from me because I couldn't find any solution , so I posted my problem and the way to solve it. that's why the question is that way.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that this was a self-answer question. (If you mention that in the question already, there's less potential for confusion in that regard.)

Comment: @CBroe , Yeah, my bad! I'll do [ANSWERED] in title from now on. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach which concatenates and collects such partials and also does limit each partial's concatenated length could be implemented similar to the next provided example code ...

```js
function concatAndCollectPartialsOfLimitedLength(collector, str) {
  const { limit = 24, list } = collector;

  const lastIdx = list.length - 1;
  const partial = list[lastIdx];

  if (partial && (partial.length + str.length + 1 <= limit)) {
    // concatenate if partial exists and if the length of its
    // next concatenated version does not exceed the limit ...

    list[lastIdx] = [partial, str].join(' ');
  } else {
    // ... otherwise provide and collect the base
    // for the following concatenation step(s).

    list.push(str);
  }
  return collector;
}

console.log(
  'concatenated partial length is limited to 24 chars ...',
  "this is the very very very very long string and some more of it and even more"
    .trim()
    .split(/\s+/)
    .reduce(concatAndCollectPartialsOfLimitedLength, { list: [] })
    .list
);
console.log(
  'concatenated partial length is limited to 13 chars ...',
  "this is the very very very very long string and some more of it and even more"
    .trim()
    .split(/\s+/)
    .reduce(
      concatAndCollectPartialsOfLimitedLength,
      { limit: 13, list: [] }
    )
    .list
);
console.log(
  'concatenated partial length is limited to 31 chars ...',
  "this is the very very very very long string and some more of it and even more"
    .trim()
    .split(/\s+/)
    .reduce(
      concatAndCollectPartialsOfLimitedLength,
      { limit: 31, list: [] }
    )
    .list
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I solved that:

```js
function stringSeperator( str, n ){
    // str: your string , n: max length of each part
    let j = 0
    let sepArr = [""]
    let strArr = str.split(" ")
    for(let i=0 ; i<strArr.length ; i++){
        if(sepArr[j].length + strArr[i].length >= n){
            j++
            sepArr[j] = ""
        }
        sepArr[j] += strArr[i] + " "
    }
    return sepArr
}
```

which will return a array of string's parts. I also added a space to end of each part that can be omitted